# Unable to install grpcio using pip install grpcio

Tags: python-2.7, build, grpc

I am getting error while installing grpcio using pip install grpcio on my windows machine.I read here - https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/17829 that it may be due to error in a version of setuptools. I upgraded my setuptools to the latest version i.e. 41.0.1 . Still getting the same build error. Its not happening for any other package. I have tried reinstalling pip and python both on my laptop. I'm attaching my error

```
Building wheels for collected packages: grpcio
Building wheel for grpcio (setup.py) ... error
ERROR: Complete output from command 'c:\python27\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'c:\\users\\s\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-install-ge5zhq\\grpcio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel
-d 'c:\users\s\appdata\local\temp\pip-wheel-txjhlh' --python-tag cp27:
  ERROR: Found cython-generated files...
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  running build_project_metadata
  creating python_build
  creating python_build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
  creating python_build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\grpc
  copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\_auth.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\grpc
  copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\_channel.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\grpc
  copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\_common.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\grpc
  copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\_compression.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\grpc
  copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\_grpcio_metadata.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\grpc
  copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\_interceptor.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\grpc
  copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\_plugin_wrapping.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\grpc
  copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\_server.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\grpc
  copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\_utilities.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\grpc
  copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\__init__.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\grpc
  creating python_build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\grpc\beta
  copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\beta\implementations.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\grpc\beta
  copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\beta\interfaces.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\grpc\beta
  copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\beta\utilities.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\grpc\beta
  copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\beta\_client_adaptations.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\grpc\beta
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\beta\_metadata.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\grpc\beta
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\beta\_server_adaptations.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\grpc\beta
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\beta\__init__.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\grpc\beta
      creating python_build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\grpc\experimental
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\experimental\gevent.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\grpc\experimental
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\experimental\session_cache.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\grpc\experimental
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\experimental\__init__.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\grpc\experimental
      creating python_build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\grpc\framework
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\frame`enter code here`work\__init__.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\grpc\framework
      creating python_build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\grpc\_cython
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\_cython\__init__.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\grpc\_cython
      creating python_build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\grpc\framework\common
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\common\cardinality.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\grpc\framework\common
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\common\style.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\grpc\framework\common
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\common\__init__.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\grpc\framework\common
      creating python_build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\grpc\framework\foundation
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\foundation\abandonment.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\grpc\framework\foundation
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\foundation\callable_util.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\grpc\framework\foundation
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\foundation\future.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\grpc\framework\foundation
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\foundation\logging_pool.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\grpc\framework\foundation
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\foundation\stream.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\grpc\framework\foundation
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\foundation\stream_util.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\grpc\framework\foundation
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\foundation\__init__.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\grpc\framework\foundation
      creating python_build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\grpc\framework\interfaces
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\interfaces\__init__.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\grpc\framework\interfaces
      creating python_build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\grpc\framework\interfaces\base
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\interfaces\base\base.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\grpc\framework\interfaces\base
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\interfaces\base\utilities.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\grpc\framework\interfaces\base
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\interfaces\base\__init__.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\grpc\framework\interfaces\base
      creating python_build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\grpc\framework\interfaces\face
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\interfaces\face\face.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\grpc\framework\interfaces\face
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\interfaces\face\utilities.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\grpc\framework\interfaces\face
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\interfaces\face\__init__.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\grpc\framework\interfaces\face
      creating python_build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\grpc\_cython\_cygrpc
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\_cython\_cygrpc\__init__.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\grpc\_cython\_cygrpc
      creating python_build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\grpc\_cython\_credentials
      copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\_cython\_credentials\roots.pem -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\grpc\_cython\_credentials
      running build_ext
      error: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
      ----------------------------------------
      ERROR: Failed building wheel for grpcio
      Running setup.py clean for grpcio
    Failed to build grpcio
```

Comment: if i specify the version to grpcio==1.20.0 , it is installing . for 1.21.1 it is not

Comment: Can you provide more information about your platform? The problem you are encountering is different from issue 17829.You will find better support submitting this bug as GitHub issue https://github.com/grpc/grpc.

Comment: Also, if you are using Cygwin, unfortunately, we don't support it...

Comment: this issue has been discussed here - https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/20831.. it seems pip has issues with the latest version of python (3.8 as of now; i m using Windows 64 version)

Comment: Could this be related to this: https://github.com/rust-lang/rustup/issues/3342 ?

Answer (score 195, accepted):

First, upgrade pip

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

Then, update the setup tools:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

---

At last, install `grpcio` using :

```
pip3 install --no-cache-dir  --force-reinstall -Iv grpcio==<version_number>
```

Comment: After hours of trying to install this on a Raspberry Pi and getting hung up on this package, I thank you. Took 2 minutes for everything after that.

Comment: For those who arrive here with Mac's running M1: the above solution doesn't work, but this one does: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66640705/how-can-i-install-grpcio-on-an-apple-m1-silicon-laptop

Comment: This worked for me and resolved a different issue on Ubuntu 18.04 x86. It kept attempting and failing to build grpcio from source (which takes 10+ minutes); once I upgraded pip and setuptools, it just found the wheel and succeeded quickly. Thanks!

Comment: For me, the only solution was to install wheels pre-compiled for Arm: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74424435/126192

Answer (score 9):

try to install using

```
grpcio==1.36.1
```

it worked in my case.

Comment: nice! this worked, just bumping the version in my requirements.txt fixed it, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

just use `python3.9`

no `EXPORT xx=xx` stuff

works in macos m1

Comment: Hi mefegni, welcome to Stackoverflow. Please expand your answer to explain how to apply it.

Comment: Python3.9 worked for me too. The other solutions unfortunately didn't work. But I also can't explain why.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into same issue using python 3.7 with setuptools is 41.0.1 while installing package that includes building wheel for gracio  ...
  Building wheel for grpcio (setup.py) ... error

```
warning: include path for stdlibc++ headers not found; pass '-stdlib=libc++' on the command line to use the libc++ standard library instead [-Wstdlibcxx-not-found]
src/python/Gracie/grpc/_cython/cygrpc.cpp:1343:14: fatal error: 'cstdlib' file not found
    #include <cstdlib>
             ^~~~~~~~~
1 warning and 1 error generated.
```

Could NOT find a way to resolve above, but 
I tried with another environment with Python 3.6.x with same setuptools 41.0.1. Somehow "setup" found the prebuilt wheel for gracio (i.e. grpcio==1.11.0), and got through setup.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me on MacOS using VScode: xcode-select --install

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**Summary** - Using previous released version [over latest version] of python worked for me.

**Details** -

I was getting below error when I used

```
FROM python:3
```

in dockerfile.
Note that python 3.12 is released just 2 days ago and after that this started failing with below error -

```
 ERROR: Could not build wheels for grpcio, grpcio-tools, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I changed dockerfile to use last release version of python as below -

```
FROM python:3.11
```

Answer (score 0):

First check https://pypi.org/project/grpcio/ for latest version number.
Then in your `requirements.txt` try to change version to latest:
`grpcio==1.59.0`
or
`grpcio==<latest_version_here>`

Then run:

`pip3 install -r requirements.txt`

It's working for my case.