# Cannot install some of requirements.txt python dependencies

Tags: python, docker, pip

I cannot figure out why when installing my python dependencies from requirements.txt pip don't complain, but when I do it from docker container, I got the following error message:

**The requirements.txt content:**

```
Flask~=1.1
grpcio
grpcio-tools
protobuf
iexfinance
numpy
pandas
pandas_datareader
pymongo
```

**I've created my container like below:**

```
docker run -it -p 8080:50051 -v ${pwd}:/app -w "/app" python:3.8-alpine
```

**I've tried to install my dependencies using this command:**

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

**Bellow some screenshot:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do the suggestions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56357794/unable-to-install-grpcio-using-pip-install-grpcio) answer help at all?

Comment: In [pip install fails with "No such file or directory: 'c++': 'c++'"](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/24556) some people recommend to install `gcc-c++`, `python3-devel` or `build-essential`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alpine Linux uses musl C, but most python wheel files are compiled for glib C. Therefore, packages that have extensions written in C/C++ need to be compiled. If you do not have a compiler installed, you will get an error.

Instead of installing a compiler and dependencies that packages might require at compile time, I suggest using a python Docker image that is not based on Alpine. For example, you can use `python:3.8-slim` or `python:3.8`, and python packages that ship Linux wheels will not have to be compiled. All of the packages listed in OP's `requirements.txt` can be installed from pre-compiled wheels if using `python:3.8-slim`.

So you can use these commands

```
docker run -it -p 8080:50051 -v ${pwd}:/app -w "/app" python:3.8-slim
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

If you are concerned about the size of the resulting image, you can also use the `--no-cache-dir` flag in `pip install` to disable caching.

Comment: This is fixed my issues, but I had to install requirements from the inside of the container. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to update alpine-SDK, which is a "meta-package" that pulls in the essential packages used to build new packages."

```
apk add --update alpine-sdk
```

I found the solution here:

[Github: docker alpine issues](https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/issues/24#issuecomment-89770836)

Comment: If you are using alpine for its small size, installing this metapackage defeats that purpose.