# Installing google's cloud text to speech python module on a raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, grpc, raspbian, glibc

Reproduce on a raspberry pi (I have a v4 B) running Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) in a terminal window by running:

```
pip3.x install google-cloud-texttospeech
python3.x
from google.cloud import texttospeech
```

I'm getting this error message regarding an incorrect version of GLIBC for cygrpc:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/pi/miniconda3/envs/assistant-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/texttospeech/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from google.cloud.texttospeech_v1.services.text_to_speech.client import (
  File "/home/pi/miniconda3/envs/assistant-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/texttospeech_v1/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .services.text_to_speech import TextToSpeechClient
  File "/home/pi/miniconda3/envs/assistant-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/texttospeech_v1/services/text_to_speech/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .client import TextToSpeechClient
  File "/home/pi/miniconda3/envs/assistant-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/texttospeech_v1/services/text_to_speech/client.py", line 24, in <module>
    from google.api_core import gapic_v1
  File "/home/pi/miniconda3/envs/assistant-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from google.api_core.gapic_v1 import config
  File "/home/pi/miniconda3/envs/assistant-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/config.py", line 23, in <module>
    import grpc
  File "/home/pi/miniconda3/envs/assistant-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/grpc/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from grpc import _compression
  File "/home/pi/miniconda3/envs/assistant-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/grpc/_compression.py", line 15, in <module>
    from grpc._cython import cygrpc
ImportError: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /home/pi/miniconda3/envs/assistant-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/grpc/_cython/cygrpc.cpython-36m-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so)
```

does anyone know of a functional configuration on raspbian 10 for this python module wrapping google text to speech api? Thanks in advance!

P.S. see this issue thread for some context https://github.com/timgrossmann/InstaPy/issues/6357
Never mind! This link is broken. See this link instead:
https://github.com/InstaPy/InstaPy/issues/6357

Comment: Your context link isn't found. Did you get errors or warning messages when you ran the pip install?

Comment: @dbmitch Sorry about that. I added a new link that should work now.

Comment: You might have to reinstall cython but here's a similar question with an answer that worked. https://stackoverflow.com/a/62500932/2419128